# Typescript Finding items within an array without for each?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays they look like this

```
array1Values: any[] = [{name: Test}, {name:Action}]
array2: any[] = [{Id: 1 Status: Test}, {Id:2 Status: Test}, {Id:3 Status: Test}, {Id:4 Status: Action}, {Id:5 Status: Nothing}]
```

I need to bring back all items from array 2 where the name exists in array 1.
So the filteredlist needs to be 
Ids 1-4 because the status of test and action exists in array 1

This is what I have however it is not working. I am not sure how to directly get the name of Status without going into the array and getting it in a foreach.

```
array2.filter(r => r.Status == 'Test')  works fine as its hardcoded
```

however since array1Values is an object array I need something like this. The reason being is array 2 has at least 20 other properties included so I need to just filter down the array based off of values found in the other array.

```
array2.filter(r => r.Status == array2.name)
```

Comment: `this.array2['Status']` will thorws an error or may be its undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make a Set of the names in `array1Values`, then `.filter` the `array2` by whether the set has the `Status` being iterated over, and then you can `.map` to the found IDs:

```
const names = new Set(array1Values.map(val => val.name));
const foundIds = array2
  .filter(({ Status }) => names.has(Status))
  .map(({ Id }) => Id);
```

```js
const Test = 'foo';
const Action = 'bar';
const Nothing = 'baz';

const array1Values = [{name: Test}, {name:Action}];
const array2 = [{Id: 1, Status: Test}, {Id:2, Status: Test}, {Id:3, Status: Test}, {Id:4, Status: Action}, {Id:5, Status: Nothing}];

const names = new Set(array1Values.map(val => val.name));
const foundIds = array2
  .filter(({ Status }) => names.has(Status))
  .map(({ Id }) => Id);
  
console.log(foundIds);
```

Note that each separate key-value pair in an object needs to be separated with a `,`. Also, make sure that your `Test`, `Action`, and `Nothing` variables are defined first.

---

If you don't need the individual matching `Id`s, but the whole object in the original `array2`, then just leave out the `.map` at the end:

```js
const Test = 'foo';
const Action = 'bar';
const Nothing = 'baz';

const array1Values = [{name: Test}, {name:Action}];
const array2 = [{Id: 1, Status: Test}, {Id:2, Status: Test}, {Id:3, Status: Test}, {Id:4, Status: Action}, {Id:5, Status: Nothing}];

const names = new Set(array1Values.map(val => val.name));
const matchingItemsInArr2 = array2
  .filter(({ Status }) => names.has(Status));
  
console.log(matchingItemsInArr2);
```

Comment: Thanks I haven't tried it but what if my object has more than just Id things like name, email, address etc? Would I have to manually map all the objects in the array?

Comment: The Set method (`O(n)`) is great for *single* values, but not for anything else. If there are more properties in both arrays of objects, the easiest method is to use a nested loop, which would make things `O(n^2)`, iterating over all properties in both the item being searched for and the item in the other array.

Comment: I updated the question on what I am looking for. A nested loop seems overly complex in this situation.

Comment: If you *just* need to check if one property value exists in the other array, then you can keep using a Set - do the same sort of thing, just don't `.map` to the individual `Id`s after filtering